# how to stretch listviewitem in listview

Tags: listview, uwp, listviewitem, stretch

developers.

I try to stretch listview item in horizontal orientation.
I do reset ItemContainerStyle ,and the horizentalalignment is strech.
Here is all code in the MainPage.xaml.

```
<Grid x:Name="rootGrid"
      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
      MinWidth="320"
      MaxWidth="480"
      Width="Auto">
    <ListView x:Name="infoFlowListView" 
              MinWidth="320"
              MaxWidth="480"
              Width="Auto"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:MyUserControl1 MinWidth="300" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></local:MyUserControl1>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Here is all code in MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public MainPage()
    {
        var items = new List<MyUserControl1>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            items.Add(new MyUserControl1());
        }
        this.InitializeComponent();
        infoFlowListView.ItemsSource = items;
    }
```

Here is all code in MyUserControl.xaml

```
<Grid>    
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"></ColumnDefinition>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="8"></RowDefinition>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Ellipse Width="60" Height="60"
         Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3"
         VerticalAlignment="Center" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
         Stretch="Uniform">
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/1.png"></ImageBrush>
    </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>

<RelativePanel x:Name="topRelativePanel"
               Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <TextBlock Text="TestName"
               VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
               RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
               FontSize="12"
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="Author"
               VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
               RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
               FontSize="12"
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
               Margin="0,0,8,0"></TextBlock>
</RelativePanel>

<TextBlock x:Name="nameTextBlock"
           Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
           Text="Name" 
           TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
           VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
           FontSize="18" >
</TextBlock>

<Grid x:Name="bottomGrid"
      Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"
      VerticalAlignment="Top"
      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
               Text="90"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
               Text="48"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2"
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
               Text="20170330 08:33"
               Margin="0,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
</Grid>

<Border Background="LightGray"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"></Border>
```

I test these code on 6inch emulator, and I add a screenshot of this example.

And the mobile emulators don't have the same result.
Here are different emulator screenshots.
[4inch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNk0Z.png)
[screen shot of example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtlYm.png)
The right side of these screenshots are different.

Comment: You probably have problems in InfoListViewItemUserControl and you haven't submitted that code. The rest seems fine.

Comment: @IvanIčin I submitted xaml of usercontrol,would you please tell me where is the problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think the answer below is correct, if you set the MaxWidth it invalidates Stretch alignement.

Comment: Could you please just provide a [mcve] project?

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT I don't know how to upload a project. So I copy all code of the example.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> I try to stretch listview item in horizontal orientation.

You need to set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` property for the `ListViewItem`, not the `HorizontalAlignment`. With the following code the content of `ListViewItem` will stretch.

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"  Value="Stretch"></Setter>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

The default `ListViewItem` [style and template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299136.aspx) doesn't open the `HorizontalAlignment` setter  but `HorizontalContentAlignment`.

Comment: That's my fault. Thanks a lot ,it is very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I think, this is because the ListView.ItemTemplate control have the MaxWidth="400" property.

Comment: I removed the maxwidth of usercontrol, but listviewitem still can't stretch in horizental orientation.